# 'send' on 'WebSocket': already in CONNECTING state error

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am using node.js & sockets.io on a mac (whilst testing). The app is being tested as a web app and also as a phonegap compiled app on IOS. The error above appeared on the web app when the PC had gone to sleep overnight and I resumed the PC.

On the web client I am using:

```
OnAppStarted{
connectSocket();
}

function connectSocket(){
socket = io.connect('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8124', {
    'reconnect': true,
    'reconnection delay': 500,
    'max reconnection attempts': 50
});

//socket = io.connect('http://81.133.36.139:8124');
socket.on('disconnect', function () { 
//app.jGrowl('disconnected ');
app.setProperty('labelTopText','fontColor','red');
});   

socket.socket.on('connect', function () { 
app.jGrowl('sockets connected');
var d = new Date();
connectedTime = JSON.stringify(d);
socket.emit('subscribe', {schoolNewsUpdated:'schoolNewsUpdated',schoolNewsClientUpdateTime : schoolNewsClientUpdateTime});
app.setProperty('labelTopText','fontColor','white');
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () { 
app.setProperty('labelTopText','fontColor','red');
});   

socket.on('update', function(data) {
//app.jGrowl('on update ');
var d = new Date();
schoolNewsClientUpdateTime = d;
if(data["schoolNewsUpdated"] === 'schoolNewsUpdated'){// && schoolNewsLastUpdateTime > data["schoolUpdatedTime"]  ){
updatedNewsDocs = 'Y';
handler_image_onClick();
}
});

}
}
```

I have the following events for when the app goes into the background.

```
function handler_application_onMobileResume(){
socket.socket.reconnect();
}


function handler_application_onMobilePause(){
socket.socket.disconnect(); 
} 

function handler_application_onMobileResume(){
socket.socket.reconnect();
}


function handler_application_onMobilePause(){
socket.socket.disconnect(); 
}
```

Server Side:

```
// live version
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8124);
var roomID;
var schoolNewsServerUpdateTime = '2014-01-10T22:52:50.904Z';
var schoolRequestedTime;
var schoolNewsClientUpdateTime;


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
roomID = data["schoolNewsUpdated"];
schoolNewsClientUpdateTime = JSON.stringify(data["schoolNewsClientUpdateTime"]);
socket.join(roomID);
console.log('joined room ' + roomID +' client update ' + schoolNewsClientUpdateTime + ' server update ' + schoolNewsServerUpdateTime);
if(schoolNewsClientUpdateTime < schoolNewsServerUpdateTime){
    console.log(' we should send an update to this client');
    socket.emit('update', {schoolNewsUpdated : 'schoolNewsUpdated'});
}
else
{
console.log(' no update as there is as he already has the latest')
}
});

socket.on('unsubscribe', function (data) {

roomID = data["schoolNewsUpdated"];
socket.leave(roomID);
console.log('left room ' + roomID);

});

socket.on('itemUpdated', function (data) {
var createdFor = data.createdFor;
var updatedChatID = data.updatedChatID;
var d = new Date();
schoolNewsServerUpdateTime = JSON.stringify(d);
console.log('sending '+ updatedChatID +' to everyone in room '+ createdFor + ' created at ' + schoolNewsServerUpdateTime);
socket.broadcast.to(createdFor).emit('update', {schoolNewsUpdated : updatedChatID});

});
});
```

So what happens is on my main 'Editor' app whenever I update a record this triggers the socket.io and sends a message to all clients in the same room. The clients then refresh the data and re-populate the controls.

Any ideas what I need to do to stop the error appearing ?

MrWarby

Comment: Consider creating a proper account here, MrWarby :)

Comment: If you created an account here, you could be distinguishable from the masses. Many user8912863s ask questions daily and it would be easier to communicate with a MrWarby than trying to remember who asked that question on an obscure issue. But of course, it's your prerogative. I'm just recommending it because you seem to have accumulated a few repuation points here, implying you mean to be around for some time.